# jboss authentication with blocked cookies

Tags: authentication, jboss, session-cookies

Is it possible to setup authentication in jboss 4.2.2 (tomcat in fact). to support clients/browsers with cookies disabled.

For now when I block all cookies in IE, after logging int, JBoss returns:
HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser

Comment: Now I don't think jboss authentication can work without cookies enabled at client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's not possible to run JBoss authentication without cookies enabled at client side.

If it's not the true or anybody find a solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss should do it automatically by appending ;jsessionid=SESSIONID to every request.

So if you are creating session when user enters your login form, you should add the ;jsessionid to login parameters.